# Can you supply me with links for new members?

Tags: support

Sometimes I'll flag a low quality answer, but I'd like to do more to help the member understand the criteria for answering question. Can someone supply me with a template of what you to post to someone in their comments to help them out? I imagine most of those who do this have the template saved to their PC, so they can copy-and-paste in the user's comments whenever they need. Thanks.

For example, "Please see [link] and [link] for yadda yadda." :)

Comment: I've tried a couple times to formulate some stock comments but haven't come up with anything I like and typically write every comment from scratch. That doesn't mean this is a bad idea (I've seen it work, e.g. David Stratton's comments on the first post review queue over on C.SE) and maybe somebody here has some. Or we can come up with some.

Comment: @Caleb I shared my user script import file.

Comment: You might also check out [my latest meta post with a flowchart for questions as I link to and quote tons of relevant meta posts as well](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/867/423)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use [the AutoReviewComment user script](https://stackapps.com/q/2116/20588) so that it actually pops up for me in the comment box and allows me to choose what to say to users.

I click on 'auto' to comment with a pre-saved comment:

[image: Auto button]

Then I select the relevant comment I want to use:

[image: Comments]

Note that some of them only show up on questions, and some only on answers (configurable by prepending `[Q]` or `[A]` before the comment title).

First, this is my site welcome post (the script automatically appends this to comments for new users, and you can force it to be included on any comment as well:

```
Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange! Be sure to take our [site tour](http://$SITEURL$/tour) to learn more about us. [We're a little different from other sites.](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/803/423)
```

And here are my preconfigured comments so that you can import them if you want. I have modified a couple of them to better fit users who are not also moderators:

```
###[Q]No sources for claims
Please give sources for who are making these claims. Saying, "some say...", "most think..." means nothing without any examples of anyone who actually think that.

###[Q]General reference
['General reference' questions that can be answered by doing a simple Google search are usually not good fits here.](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/635/423) Be sure to put forth some minimal research effort prior to asking a question here.

###[Q]More than one question asked
The question-and-answer format of this site works best if you put each question in a separate question post. Please edit your post down to one question, and create new posts to ask any further questions. You'll get better answers that way.

###[Q]OP having trouble writing good questions
I'm very grateful for your participation here, but I've noticed that you seem to be struggling with asking questions that are received well on this site. You may benefit from checking out [this helpful flowchart for asking questions](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/867/423).

###[Q]OP asks for application
We don't do 'Bible study' — we study the Bible. That means we stop short of application when answering questions about the Bible (which means we don't fully exegete the text in the religious sense of the practice). [Questions should be focused solely on the text](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/207/423) and not primarily on those things to which the text applies.

###Preaching
[Please don't "preach" at readers.](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/1015/423) Instead, *describe* your perspective without *prescribing* it. We're looking for lectures rather than sermons. Please keep in mind that [not all of your readers here are Christians](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/441/423).

###[Q]Original language assumption
If you don't know the language you are asking about, [please keep speculation to a minimum](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/845/423) (preferably none at all). We understand that sometimes you don't know what to ask if you don't know the language, but it is best to simply ask what the word/clause means or if it is translated correctly in a specified translation.

###Use of Strongs Concordance as lexicon
Claiming the meaning of a specific word in a given context on the basis of the *Strong's Concordance* is not a reliable claim. [Please see this post which explains how to effectively (and properly) use *Strong's Concordance*.](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/923/423)

###Etymological fallacy
[Etymology and the later meaning of a word are often non-related concepts](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/923/423). For instance, no sensible person would understand 'butterfly' to refer to an airborne dairy product. Etymology is not the primary tool for understanding the meaning of a word in a specific context, and it is often meaningless when making such a determination.

###Excessive tangential content
"Except for truly exceptional situations, never allow the garnish to be larger than the meat and potatoes of an answer" ([meta](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/643/423)). "Opinions and tangents should be garnishes, not the entire meal. If a post is essentially an opinion-based argument or testimony, it doesn't fit and will need to be removed or edited" ([meta](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/777/423)). I've edited this to remove the tangential content.

###Outdated lexicon
Virtually all Greek-English lexical resources written prior to the 20th century are now obsolete and not considered to be reliable sources for the meaning of Greek words. [Please use a more updated lexicon, here is a list.](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/642/423)

###OP providing facts in a comment
The best way to add additional information to your post is by editing it, with the **edit** button. It is more visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your post should be in the post itself.

###Does not show work
This doesn't [show its work](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/846/423), which is a [*requirement*](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/777/423) on this site. Don't just tell us *what* you know, tell us *how* you know it.

###Text citation issue
Be sure to [properly cite the text](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/810/423) you're asking about. The chapter and verse numbers do not always line up between the Hebrew, Greek, and English texts. 

###OP assumes this is a Christian site
Please keep in mind that [this is not a Christian site](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/441/423). Be sure to [check out what makes us different from other sites that study the Bible](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/803/423).

###OP has an axe to grind
If you are here to convince someone of your point of view, [you are probably in the wrong place](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/803/423). If you're here to answer questions while contributing your perspective in a diverse, pluralistic setting, welcome aboard! Stack Exchange sites are based on a question-and-answer model. If your goal in writing an answer or a question is to "make a point," then sadly, you've missed the point of this site!

###[A]Answers just to say Thanks!
Please don't add "thanks" as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](http://$SITEURL$/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the $SITENAME$ way of saying thank you.

###[A]Nothing but a URL (and isn't spam)
Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here (summarize the relevant portions of the resource that answer this question), and provide the link for reference.

###[A]Requests to OP for further information
This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://$SITEURL$/privileges/comment). For the moment I've flagged this post to be converted into a comment.

###[A]OP adding a new question as an answer
This is more of a question than an answer. If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://$SITEURL$/questions/ask) button. For the moment I've flagged this post to be converted into a comment.

###[A]Another user adding a 'Me too!'
If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://$SITEURL$/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](http://$SITEURL$/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.
```

As a caveat, some of these are too long when combined with the welcome, and it is often best to tailor the comment to the situation a bit. Also, you may not like my tone or whatnot in these comments and may wish to modify them. For what it's worth, I don't always like the tone of my comments and often modify them before posting. These are more or less templates for me to get me started.

Comment: Great! I loaded these up and if I make any improvements I'll try to contribute them back here. Thanks for posting.

Comment: Thanks Dan!...........

Comment: @Dan, Is this feature available only for moderators or folks of a certain reputation?

Comment: @Sarah nope, any user can download and use this user script.

Comment: We do not use Google Chrome, we use Firefox.  Will it still work?

Comment: @Sarah it should work in any browser, as explained in the instructions on the link.

Comment: The link doesn't mention IE, I don't think it will work there, so not 'any browser'.

Comment: @JackDouglas, that's okay; IE isn't a real browser. :)

Comment: Exactly, IE is a downloader application so that you can obtain a real browser :P (but seriously, good observation - it doesn't appear to work in IE).